# Using Conditional statement for calculations

Tags: conditional-statements

```
CASE WHEN segment2 = 2345 THEN a-b
    END AS debit
CASE WHEN segment2 = 3245 THEN a-b
    END AS credit
debit-credit as amount
```

It is not taking the alias name for calculation?

Comment: I see a typo in `segmen2` misssing the `t`, I don't think that's intentional.

Comment: Yes its a typo, in both cases column is segment2